# fail safe iterator in ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, collections

Iterators in both  `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and `ConcurrentHashMap`  are fail-safe and do not throw CME.

IN `CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>` iterator is built on a **snapshot** of 
original underlying array. So iterator here is **fail-safe** and also **thread-safe.**

Javadcos for `CopyOnWriteArrayList<E>`  clearly states term **snapshot** .

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of
>   the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException.

Does in case of `ConcurrentHashMap` iterator also built on **snapshot** of original underlying map?

Thanks...

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily - cf [the javadoc (emphasis mine)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table **at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration**.

If you look at the `values`, `entrySet` and `keySet` methods:

> The view's iterator [...] guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction.